# How to change sqlite get function?

Tags: function, sqlite, go, web

how can I change my Get function so that it just returns one Equipment-Objekt?

```
func GetEquipmentByID(Id string) (equipment Equipment, err error) {
    equipment = Equipment{}
    err = Db.QueryRow("select ID, Name, Description, ImgPath, Category, Availability, Amount, Storage from Equipment where Id = $1", Id).Scan(&equipment.ID, &equipment.Name, &equipment.Description, &equipment.ImgPath, &equipment.Category, &equipment.Availability, &equipment.Amount, &equipment.Storage)
    return 
}
```

I want to use this function to fill an Equipment Array in my Controller. But now it doesnt work, because my function returns 2 objects (Equipment and Error)

I want to use it here:

```
    func Cart(w http.ResponseWriter,    r   *http.Request)  {
        data := CartData{ 
        Name: "Cart",
        Equipment: model.GetEquipment(model.Db),
        CartList: nil,  
        Pages: []Page{
            {
                Title: "Meine Geräte", 
                Active: false,
                Link: "/my-equipment",
            },
            {
                Title: "Equipment", 
                Active: false,
                Link: "/equipment",
            },
            {
                Title: "Logout",
                Active: false,
                Link: "/logout",
            },
        },

    }

        session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")


      list := session.Values["EquipmentIDs"].(string)

      result := strings.Split(list, ",")
      for i := range result {
            fmt.Print(i)
            fmt.Println(result[i])
        }



     for i:= range result {
equipment, err := model.GetEquipmentByID(result[i])
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
data.CartList[i] = equipment // ERROR BECAUSE OF THIS LINE
}



        tmpl:= template.Must(template.ParseFiles("template/base_user.html", "template/cart.html"))
        tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "base", data)
        }
    }
```

So my second question is, how can I pass the array in my cart function as data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The append-method solved my problem.

```
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")
    list := session.Values["EquipmentIDs"].(string)

      result := strings.Split(list, ",")
      for i := range result {
            fmt.Print(i)
            fmt.Println(result[i])
        }

var List[]model.Equipment

        for i := range result {
        equipment, err := model.GetEquipmentByID(result[i])
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        fmt.Println(i)
        fmt.Println(equipment)
        List = append(List,equipment)
    //  List[i] = equipment
    //  data.CartList[i] = equipment
        }


fmt.Println(List)
    data := CartData{ 
    Name: "Cart",
    Equipment: model.GetEquipment(model.Db),
    CartList: List,
    Pages: []Page{
        {
            Title: "Meine Geräte", 
            Active: false,
            Link: "/my-equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Equipment", 
            Active: false,
            Link: "/equipment",
        },
        {
            Title: "Logout",
            Active: false,
            Link: "/logout",
        },
    },

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In the future I will try to improve the quality of my posts.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, never ignore errors. For example,

```
equipment, err := model.GetEquipment(model.Db)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
data := CartData{ 
    Name: "Cart",
    Equipment: equipment,
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Changed my post. Now i got following error message: undefined CartList

Comment: This is where the error is located: Cart[i] = equipment

Comment: @ChristopherG1994: `CartList[i] = equipment`: error `undefined CartList`: `data.CartList[i] = equipment`.

Comment: This give me following error: for i:= range result {
equipment, err := model.GetEquipmentByID(result[i])
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
fmt.Println(equipment)
data.CartList[i] = equipment
}          
panic serving [::1]:60965: runtime error: index out of range

Comment: maybe it's because of Cart: nil, in CartData but what do I have to use else?

Comment: Did this:  List = append(List,equipment)

Now it works